# how to to rollup the field for custom object?

Tags: apex, bestpractice, roll-up-summary

i am having 1 custom object capital adjustment with a field name tax. i want to roll up this tax value to another custom object contact(i cant able to look up with the capital adjustment). please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

As @Devendra states, if there is a master detail relationship present, then just use the rollup summary fields provided by standard SF functionality.

If a Master-Detail relationship doesn't exist and its just a lookup relationship, then you would need to create this functionality yourself.  While you could do this on your own with triggers, there are already a few great products out there so why reinvent the wheel.  Here are a few I would recommend checking out

[Rollup Helper](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI) - Nice little App Exchange app with very little technical coding skill needed.  Has a free version, but youd likely need to upgrade to the paid version if you want automatic rollups

[Declarative Rollup Tool](https://andyinthecloud.com/2016/06/19/declarative-rollup-tool-summer-release/) - An excellent free tool.  This one does require some coding knowledge and can seem a bit intimidating at first, but its amazing the functionality that Andy has built and shared with people for free.  Great tool

Answer (score 0):

Roll-up summary fields calculate values from a set of related records, such as those in a related list. You can create roll-up summary fields that automatically display a value on a master record based on the values of records in a detail record. These detail records must be directly related to the master through a master-detail relationship.

So, you need to Define roll-up summary fields on the object that is on the master side of a master-detail relationship. If a relationship does not already exist, first create a master-detail relationship between the master object that displays the value and the detail object containing the records you are summarizing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use rollup summary if their is no MasterDetails.Use Trigger For that it will solve your problem

Comment: could you please share some example